# Clean URL htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I rewrite http://localhost/index.php?page=sample into http://localhost/page/sample.

The only code inside my htaccess is the rule to remove index.php on the url.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /(.+/)?index\.(html?|php)(\?.*)?\  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+/)?index\.(html?|php)$ ./$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ ./index.php?page=$1  [QSA,L]
```

I am looking for rewriting the part with the parameter.
 Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule would be this:

```
RewriteRule ^page/([a-zA-Z0-9]+) index.php?page=$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: I'm getting error 404. Do I just need to add that line after my initial code?

Comment: I think if you add it to the beginning of your .htaccess would solve the 404 error.

Comment: I added that to the beginning, but no avail. In order for me to access the url, I need to type this url "http://localhost/?page=sample"

Comment: I think your other rules are messing with the rule above. try removing all other rules.

Comment: The only left in my code is RewriteEngine On + your code. But still can't achieve the goal.

Comment: That's weird! It works just fine for me. Are you sure `index.php` actually exists in your root path?

Comment: I am developing in a Ubuntu box, if that matters. But I can't still ahive the goal.

Comment: It works now, I just enable mod_rewrite in Ubuntu apache. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to hack to remove "index.php" with RewriteRules. In your vhost, or per-directory conf (or maybe `.htaccess` file I don't know), if you've put a rule like:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

Then it should work straight out of the box.

So I'll do as if your rule don't exist, because they're useless (unless you show me why).

You want a user to type in the browser: `http://localhost/page/sample` and to be internally on the server side modified to: `http://localhost/index.php?page=sample`.

This should work:

```
# if it's neither a file nor a directory:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}!-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}!-d
RewriteRule /([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /index.php?$1=$2 [QSA,L]
```

---

### Two hints:

If you're not in a hosted environment (= if it's your own server and you can modify the virtual hosts, not only the `.htaccess` files), try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

---

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)

Comment: I encountered Error 500, I'll notify if it worked the way it should be.