# Rewrite rule for form submit

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am very newbie to this. I have a form that has 4 fields. Field1 - 4 method GET. so when i submit the form The url becomes 
mydomain.com/page.php?field1=f1&field2=f2&field3=F3&field4=f4.

I want to change this to 
mydomain.com/newPath/f1/f2/F3/f4/

Answer (score 0):

You actually want a redirect then. You would rewrite

```
domain.com/path/a/b/c/d
```

to

```
domain.com/path/?w=a&x=b&y=c&z=d
```

But if you want the server to direct a request like this

```
domain.com/path/?w=a&x=b&y=c&z=d
```

to one like this, you are actually redirecting users.

```
domain.com/path/a/b/c/d
```

Comment: Yes Leeish I want to redirect users. The formal is i am able to achieve, but not the later.

Answer (score 0):

You want a 301 redirect, because then it will hide the new URL with the ampersands:

This is called clean URLs and you can achieve it with regex that accomodate your need in the htaccess file:

[Clean URL htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8861168/clean-url-htaccess)